# transferring files form an external hard drive to ubuntu?

Tags: external-hdd, macosx

I have a mac mini that is a couple of years old and was thinking of installing ubuntu. will there be any problems when I try to transfer my files from an external hard drive formatted for OS X?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It really depends how you've formatted your external drive. Can you please check how it is formatted, [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/391912/edit) and add the information?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't really be any issues that I can foresee.   This posting should help you.

https://superuser.com/questions/439571/can-i-make-a-mac-hard-drive-recognizable-on-ubuntu-11-10

From what it says there shouldn't be any issues.